# How to set respond header values in Spring Boot rest service method?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Newbie question... I'm building my first Spring Boot restful service. My restful service design requires some data to be returned in the response header.

How do I set response header values inside my controller class method?

Answer (score 38):

From the Spring Documentation:

```
@RequestMapping("/handle")
public ResponseEntity<String> handle() {
    URI location = ...;
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setLocation(location);
    responseHeaders.set("MyResponseHeader", "MyValue");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello World", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

**Source**:

- [ResponseEntity - Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html)

Comment: Not able to understand where this method should be present ResponseEntity . I am following this page to create a service https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/  and need to have the response message contain the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

Comment: Instead of returning a “Greeting” object, return a ResponseEntity, with the greeting object as the body, and also you can add the headers to the response entity. Take a look at the available constructors.

Answer (score 24):

I was looking for an answer, and I don't like to have to create a response entity - `ResponseEntity<T>`. I found the solution on the spring-forums, so credits to the writer.

In short, you can request the response in the method-declaration, so this can be populated.

A simple example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/car/{carId}", method = RequestMethod.Get)
@ResponseBody
public Car getCarById(@PathVariable("carId") String Id, HttpServletResponse response) {

    response.setHeader("X-Special-Header", myCar.getEcoLabel());
    //get the car
    return myCar;
}
```

Hope this helps others as well.

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web-services/102652-setting-header-values-with-spring-rest-controller

Comment: I was looking for this one . Setting header without using response entity

Answer (score 19):

Unlike the other answer, **don't** use `HttpServletResponse`. You don't wanna be working with low-level Servlet APIs if you can avoid it. Return a [ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) or `HttpEntity`.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("1", "uno");

return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: I'm agree with you, working with low level servlet APIs caused some issue for me and your solution is awesome. Thanks.

Comment: I've recently upgraded to Spring boot 1.4.7, now this method doesn't pass some of the set headers (it was working before) . is it supposedly discouraged or there is a bug in 1.4.7?

Comment: @nafas I suggest opening a new question with more information than "doesn't work". This answer solved the original problem when it was written; it doesn't make any guarantees to work for the next 100 years.

Answer (score 8):

To set Response Header there are multiple ways:

1. As mentioned by @Matias Elorriaga, you can use this to add header to single response.
2. **Or**, To add header to **all responses** you can also add java Filters.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/*"})
@Component
public class ResponseHeaderFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        res.setHeader("My-Custom-Header", "Header-Value-Here");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

3. **Or,** In Spring 5, you can also have WebFilter to add headers to **all responses**.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;

@Component
public class ResponseHeaderWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("My-Custom-Header", "My-Value-Here");
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works with first way of doing 
@javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/*"})
@Component
public class ResponseHeaderFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping(path="/receive")
    public ResponseEntity<Map> handleoptional(@RequestParam(value ="field", defaultValue = "nothing", required = false ) String field)
    {
        Map data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("received", field);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("sample_header", "sample_header_value");
        return new ResponseEntity<Map>(data, map, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Above code will sent response body , response header, response status code