# Send custom headers RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am trying to set a custom header on my `RestTemplate` requests. I'm using `Spring Boot 2.0.6.RELEASE`

I try setting them like so, inside of my public method

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.add("muh Header", "muh value");
```

Every time I try and do this, it generates the following error

`'HttpHeaders(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>>)' has private access in 'java.net.http.`

I understand the error message to mean that I'm trying to instantiate a private class outside of the class where the private class is declared.

So what is the best course of action?

Comment: there is a similar question being asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45152484/how-to-set-respond-header-values-in-spring-boot-rest-service-method however I have checked and Found out they are using the same approach as you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with something like this:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class WebController {
    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public ResponseEntity<String> greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name){
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.add("thisiskey", "this is value");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(name, headers, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
}
```

[image]

Points to ponder :

1. How often do you want to add a custom header and how often do they vary?
   If it is only applicable to one or two, you may consider this option however if it is more then twice i would suggest to use a http interceptor.
2. header.add("","") -> which implements MultiValueMap does not accept a header.add("mua key", "...") -> as there is a space in the key.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an interceptor which intercepts all the requests sent by the rest template and add the custom headers like so,

```
public class TokenAuthorizationInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
            throws IOException {
        request.getHeaders().add("ContentType", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        request.getHeaders().add("muh Header", "muh value");
        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }

}

this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
this.restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new TokenAuthorizationInterceptor());
```

This will work fine if you want to add the same custom headers to all your requests sent through this rest template. One advantage of this approach is you can set custom HTTP headers only in one single place, rather than doing it in everywhere you submit a request.

Answer (score 1):

The package you are using is wrong, in order to add headers when using Spring restTemplate, you should use `org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.HttpHeaders` instead of `java.net.http.HttpHeaders`, the latter is what you are trying to use.

Here is the code snippet that adds request headers.

```
// request resource
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("headerName", "headerValue");

HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("some url", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

Comment: This was an issue also, very annoying hah.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner way to do so :

```
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .header("key","value")
            .contentType(-----)
            .body(----------);
}
```