# How to add custom header in 204 response (NO_CONTENT)?

Tags: java, rest, httpresponse, http-delete

I have the following endpoint:

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "204", content = {@Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = UserDTO.class))}, description = "Successful")
})
@DeleteMapping("/Users/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<String> deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    userService.deleteUser(id);
    return ResponseEntity.noContent().header("Successfully deleted", "0").build();
}
```

And I need to customise 204 response - return not just status and empty body but 204 code + body which will be contained "Successfully deleted" message. I've tried to add header manually (in code above), but it didn't work properly.
Could you give me a piece of advice - how can I add it by different way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set respond header values in Spring Boot rest service method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45152484/how-to-set-respond-header-values-in-spring-boot-rest-service-method)

Comment: http 204 is defined as "no content", so i suppose setting a body will be ignored by spring... e.g. using `http 202 - accepted` could be an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marc correctly pointed out in his comment, returning `204` and a body at the same time makes no sense, as that is not what `204` signifies. I suggest you simply return the following:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>("Successfully deleted", HttpStatus.OK);
```

You don't really need any custom headers for what you described, but if you still feel the need for one, you can do it  like so

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("custom-header", "value");
return new ResponseEntity<>("Successfully deleted", headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```