# Implementing Deprecated Header in HTTP Response

Tags: java, spring, deprecated, deprecation-warning, response-headers

I am trying to implement deprecation header for api responses in my application. The problem is that recently our codebase has gone through major refactoring and restructuring with lots of apis being deprecated. all of these api endpoints are annotated with @Deprecated. is there anyway i can use this annotation to change the response without having to make code changes at each and every endpoint location?

I have tried to change response in the code at each location and this would be tedious, expecting a smarter way to go about this.

Note- My application is in JAVA and uses spring-boot framework.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, it looks like there's no automatic way to do this in Spring. I also thought the @Deprecated annotation would have done the trick.

So apparently the only way to do this is to manually add headers per your preferred method. See the following SO thread on a few ways to do that, but the gist is that you'll have to create a headers object and populate it with 'Deprecated' set to 'true' manually:

[How to set respond header values in Spring Boot rest service method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45152484/how-to-set-respond-header-values-in-spring-boot-rest-service-method)

And if you want to be thorough, you can also set an alternate link and sunset date:

https://imhoratiu.wordpress.com/2021/01/20/respectful-rest-apis-sunset-and-deprecation-http-headers/

Here are example headers for deprecating with a 'sunset' date:

```
Deprecation: 01 Jan 2031 00:00:00 GMT
Link: http://reviews/search?filter=pattern; rel="alternate",https://new-url; rel="deprecation"
Sunset: 31 Dec 2021 23:59:59 GMT
```